# Prompt when trying to dial a phone number using tel:// scheme on iOS 11

Tags: ios11, swift4, openurl, xcode9-beta, tel

I am facing an issue, while trying to start a phone call from my iOS app using:

`UIApplication open(_:options: completionHandler:)`

iOS shows an confirmation popup/alert before starting the call with two button Call & Cancel and CompletionHandler called with a Bool parameter having true/false based on button action in iOS 10.

But now in iOS11 the problem is that the completionHandler is being called automatically before tapping on "Cancel" or "Call" button of confirmation popup, always having true value.

Is this a bug in iOS11 or is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am facing the similar issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a behavior change in when the closure is called in iOS 11. I cant say if this behavior will be reverted or if this is a bug. 
But one of the ways you can identify when the user interacted with the popup is by adding a notification listener around UIApplicationDidBecomeActive in the completion closure of openURL(). To identify whether the call was clicked or not you will need to create another custom notification and listener on the CTCallCenter. That was the best way through which I was able to identify it, there might be better solutions though :D

Answer (score 0):

completionHandler will get a call if your given URL gets open success or failure, this has nothing to do with Cancel & Call buttons on Alert

see what Apple docs has to say about it [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open)

> **completionHandler**
>
> The block to execute with the results. Provide a
> value for this parameter if you want to be informed of the success or
> failure of opening the URL. This block is executed asynchronously on
> your app's main thread. The block has no return value and takes the
> following parameter:
>
> **success**
>
> A Boolean indicating whether the URL was
> opened successfully.

Comment: I have already gone through the Apple docs and thats fine that completionHandler will get called based on given URL (success/failure). But  then what is the meaning of call confirmation popup shown to the user due to this method call if Cancel/Call tap doesn't matter?

Comment: that alert put up by iOS so that any application should not use your call capability to make call. iOS let you know before using this. User say yes or no, there's no track of that.

Comment: I am not talking about permission popup that is different thing, its about call confirmation popup which iOS always shows when app tries to start phone call.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug to apple.

Comment: I have get a response from Apple?

Comment: No, not yet. They just told me that this is a duplicate bug post.

Comment: Did anyone get a response on it yet ?

Comment: If your aim is to know when the phone call is terminated, can you not look for the moment your app becomes active again? Perhaps there is something in that call's parameters. There's the method in your app's delegate (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive) and there's also a notification being fired.